# Requests: Error sending payload in python post request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

The code behaving strangely that I am unable to understand what's going on..

**The code that works fine:**

```
link = "https://api.luminati.io/dca/trigger_immediate?collector=XXXxxxXXXxxxXXXX" 
head = {"Authorization": "Bearer xxXXxxXXxx" ,"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data = '{"url":"https://www.practo.com/pune/doctor/XXXXXXxXXXXX"}'
res = requests.post(link, headers = head, data = data)
print("Status: "+str(res.status_code), "Message: "+res.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Status: 202 Message: {"response_id":"z7627t1617552745375r14623bt37oo"}
```

**But I want to load** `"url":"https://www.practo.com/pune/doctor/XXXXXXxXXXXX"` **this thing dynamically.**

```
url = "https://www.practo.com/pune/doctor/XXXXXXxXXXXX"
link = "https://api.luminati.io/dca/trigger_immediate?collector=XXXxxxXXXxxxXXXX" 
head = {"Authorization": "Bearer xxXXxxXXxx" ,"Content-Type": "application/json"}
data = {"url":url} 
res = requests.post(link, headers = head, data = data)
print("Status: "+str(res.status_code), "Message: "+res.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Status: 500 Message: 'Unexpected token u in JSON at position 7'
```

Comment: You probably want `json=data` as your post parameter

Comment: @OneCricketeer  didn't understood it.

Comment: Try replacing `data=data` with `json=data` if your endpoint expects a json payload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load data dynamically try using %s string feature, like that:

```
url = "https://www.practo.com/pune/doctor/XXXXXXxXXXXX"
data = '{"url":"%s"}' % url
```

or you can convert dictionary entirely to str, like:

```
import json
data = {"url":link}
res = requests.post(link, headers=head, data=json.dumps(data))
```

by the way, you can pass body not like data, but like json, here's documents:

:param json: (optional) json data to send in the body of the :class:`Request`. So your request will look like:

```
data = {"url":link}
res = requests.post(link, headers=head, json=data)
```

Comment: Would be better to build a dict rather than use string formatting

Comment: @OneCricketeer entirely agree, good catch, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
any_dynamic_variable='XXXXXXxXXXXX'#You can make your websit or part of the url to be dynamic
url = f'https://www.practo.com/pune/doctor/{any_dynamic}'
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer xxXXxxXXxx" ,"Content-Type": "application/json"}
payload={
    'your_key':'your_value',
    'currancy':'CA',#<==== This is an example
}
r = requests.post(url,headers=headres,data=payload}
print(r.status_code)#check your status to be able to find the error if you have any
print(r.text)
```